# wxWindow not getting event once we will make it parent of the SDL Window

Tags: wxwidgets, sdl-2

In my application I have a parent window created using wxWindow and have a child window on which I'm doing my rendering, this window is created using SDL 2.0.
So once I will set the SDL window as a child of wxWindow using SetParent call, all the key board events like key press, key release etc. will go to the child window instead of the parent window.

Following is the dummy code:

---

wxWindow* pParentWindow = new wxWindow();

SDL_Window* pChildWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Player", 100, 100, nWindowWidth, nWindowHeight, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

SDL_SysWMinfo SysInfo; //Will hold child Window information
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(pChildWindow , &SysInfo);

HWND SDLHandle = SysInfo.info.win.window;

SetParent(SDLHandle, (HWND)pParentWindow);

---

After this point SDL window become child of wxWindow, now whenever I'll press any key this event will go only to the child (SDL) window. But I required these event in parent window.

So can anyone please let me know how can I get these events either in my parent window (wxWindow) instead of SDL window or propagate it to the parent window.

Note: I'm using wxWidget 2.8 and SDL 2.0.

Comment: Please add more description of question.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails ( i.e. you cannot get SDL and wxWidgets to play nicely ) you might consider hooking the keyboard.

```
/**

 Callback for low level keyboard hook

*/
LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
     PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) (lParam);

// If key is being pressed
if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
    switch(p->vkCode) {
       ...
    }

}
return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}




// Set windows hook

HHOOK keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
    WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
    keyboardHookProc,
    GetModuleHandle (0),  
    //hInstance,
    0);
if( ! keyboardHook ) {
    printf("Keyboard hook failed\n");
}
```

Comment: My application have multiple panels and frames, SDL window is one of them. Above issue is only occurring when SDL window is in focus, If focus is on any other window I'm getting key events. By applying _keyboardHook_ approach I'll get duplicate events when focus is not on SDL window.

Comment: As mentioned this is not the ideal solution, only a last resort if you cannot get SDL to cooperate with wxWidgets.  To deal with the case you mention, the hook code should check which window has the focus and do nothing ( except call CallNextHookEx ) unless the SDL window has focus.